# Laravel Passport or Sanctum for Third Party Authorization

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport, laravel-sanctum

I am developing apis in `laravel` which will be used by `some external companies`.
Here I am confused that should I use `Laravel Sanctum or Passport (Personal access token)` for third party companies authorization and give them access to private apis?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

I does not really matter. Both packets can issue tokens or cookies. Passport is overkill of you only use tokens and that's it.